# Arrow from Free and MonadFree

Tags: haskell, monads, arrows, free-monad

How to create an `Arrow` from `Free` and `MonadFree` ?

```
class (Functor f, Monad m) => MonadFree f m where ...

data Free f a = Impure (f (Free f a)) | Pure a
```

MonadFree contains 2 parameters `m` and `f` , but `Kleisli` has no space to insert `f`, so we cannot use `Kleisli` arrow for `MonadFree`.

As I understand, it is needed to create a class, a newtype and an instance, like these:

```
class Arrow a => ArrowFunctor f a | a -> f where
    afmap :: a b (f c)

newtype FKleisli f m a b = FKleisli { runFKleisli :: a -> f (m b) }

instance (Functor f, Monad m, MonadFree f m) => 
         ArrowFunctor (FKleisli f m a) where ...
```

But it looks like implementation is not trival

Comment: Have you tried `Kleisli (FreeT f m)`?

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher Would you like to write that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If `m'` is an instance of `Monad`, then `Kleisli m'` is an instance of `Arrow` (and a bunch of other, related typeclasses like `ArrowApply`).

In your case, you want to use `FreeT f m` as the underlying monad (for some  `Functor f` and `Monad m`), so you can just set `m'` to `FreeT f m` and get exactly what you want: `Kleisli (FreeT f m)`.